# How can i get the role defined for current user in sharepoint rest api

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am integrating sharepoint in Iphone app.
I want to hide/unhide few UI component on the basis of User role/permission defined in sharepoint.

Please suggest me any straight query to get the role object or any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Please add some code block to support your question. This is way too broad for asking the community.

Answer (score 0):

use REST to get groups and go from there: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx